# An error occurred while calling o3245.saveAsTable

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have UDF which is installed on cluster, out put of this UDF is BooleanType.

I have used above UDF and created one column on dataframe and I got the result which is bollenType, the problem here is I can display dataframe which I am able to view the data. But when write the data frame then it is giving me error saying that "An error occurred while calling o4406.saveAsTable.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted."

I have tried below ways:

1. Without using UDF I can write the dataframe.
2. when I use UDF and try to write it was giving me above error.
3. when I use UDF and filter above dataframe with less number of records then it was writing.

I really surprised here, Request you to help me on this.

## below code is working

1. df= spark.table("default.tbl_test1")

   2. df = df.withColumn('baubar',f.expr("simple_sat_checker_udf(ruleToCheck)"))
   3. df = df.select("A","B","C","D","E","F","baubar").distinct()
   4. df2 = df.filter(df.E=='(219+411+W68)')
   5. display(df2)
   6. df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('default.tbl_test100')

Note: when I remove line #4 then it is giving above error.

error info:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2739750082465973> in <module>
      5 df2 = df
      6 #display(df2)
----> 7 df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('default.tbl_test100')
      8 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    804         if format is not None:
    805             self.format(format)
--> 806         self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
    807 
    808     def json(self, path, mode=None, compression=None, dateFormat=None, timestampFormat=None,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2154.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:360)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.$anonfun$writeFiles$8(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:427)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag(DeltaLogging.scala:171)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag$(DeltaLogging.scala:158)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.withOperationTypeTag(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$6(DeltaLogging.scala:136)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:186)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:184)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordFrameProfile(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:135)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:330)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:444)
    at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
    at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:419)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:339)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:330)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:302)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:139)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:98)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:410)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:134)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.recordDeltaOperation(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.$anonfun$recordWriteFilesOperation$1(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:210)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:1585)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.recordWriteFilesOperation(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:209)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.writeFiles(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:231)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.writeFiles$(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:225)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.writeFiles(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:475)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWriteEdge.writeFiles$(TransactionalWriteEdge.scala:466)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:212)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:331)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.$anonfun$run$2(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:142)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag(DeltaLogging.scala:171)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.withOperationTypeTag$(DeltaLogging.scala:158)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.withOperationTypeTag(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:54)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$6(DeltaLogging.scala:136)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:186)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:184)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordFrameProfile(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:54)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:135)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$1(UsageLogging.scala:330)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:444)
    at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:33)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:94)
    at com.databricks.logging.Log4jUsageLoggingShim$.withAttributionContext(Log4jUsageLoggingShim.scala:31)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:205)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:204)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:225)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:419)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:339)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:330)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:302)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:20)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:139)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:98)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:410)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:54)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:134)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordDeltaOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:54)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.run(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:118)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog.com$databricks$sql$transaction$tahoe$catalog$DeltaCatalog$$createDeltaTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.commitStagedChanges(DeltaCatalog.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.$anonfun$writeToTable$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:504)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1715)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:590)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:721)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:652)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 37.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 37.0 (TID 316) (10.21.80.10 executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (UDFRegistration$$Lambda$6494/577695565: (string) => boolean)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:835)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:690)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.logicng.io.parsers.ParserException: Parse cancellation exception when parsing the formula
    at org.logicng.io.parsers.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:118)
    at com.daimler.variety_management.java_wrappers.SimpleSatChecker.call(SimpleSatChecker.scala:28)
    at com.daimler.variety_management.java_wrappers.SimpleSatChecker.call(SimpleSatChecker.scala:11)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.$anonfun$register$352(UDFRegistration.scala:763)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recoverInline(BailErrorStrategy.java:66)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.match(Parser.java:206)
    at org.logicng.io.parsers.LogicNGPropositionalParser.formula(LogicNGPropositionalParser.java:142)
    at org.logicng.io.parsers.LogicNGPropositionalParser.getParsedFormula(LogicNGPropositionalParser.java:89)
    at org.logicng.io.parsers.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recoverInline(BailErrorStrategy.java:61)
    ... 33 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3088)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3035)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3029)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3297)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3238)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3226)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
```

Comment: add the code - otherwise it's not possible

Comment: Can you post full exception? There will be information about why the job failed when you expand the error

Comment: You need to post more code - for the UDF itself, how it's registered, etc.

Comment: pasted full exception. sorry UDF is not in my control which is handled by other team.

Comment: Alex, request you to update on this